# What kind of hash function does Aerospike use for UDF modules?

Tags: hash, user-defined-functions, aerospike, nosql

Aerospike allows to list already loaded UDF modules. Here is an **aql**-example ([taken from help-portal](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/#listing-modules)):

```sql
SHOW MODULES
```

The result contains `hash` field:

```
aql> show modules
+---------------------------+-------+------------------------+
| module                    | type  | hash                   |
+---------------------------+-------+------------------------+
| "example1.lua"            | "lua" | "033671e05067888fce09" |
| "example2.lua"            | "lua" | "07b42082cca8e73a96b2" |
+---------------------------+-------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 secs)
```

**My question (1)**: I have the `example1.lua` file (sources of the UDF module), how to calculate (and check) hash for it?

My hypotheses:

1. hash depends on source file - **TRUE**
2. hash depends on timestamp of loading - *failed*
3. hash depends on filename - **TRUE**
4. `md5sum` on source file - *failed* (obviously, see hypothesis 3)
5. `sha1sum` on pure source file - *failed* (see hypothesis 3)

Actually, I want to check the version for already registered module, and upgrade that module if necessary. As mentioned in the documentation:

> the hash value of the file. Most users will not find the hash value useful, but some may use it to verify the version or instance of a UDF on the server.

So, the **alternate question (2)** is: how to check the version of a registered UDF module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a 20-byte sha1 hash of the below 3 fields represented as a json document. The json document is string representation without any newline separator or EOF character.

```
"content64" : base64 encoding of whole file
"type" : LUA
"name" : filename
```

Example :

```
{"content64": "ZnVuY3Rpb24gcHJpbnRfbWV0YShyZWMpCgoJaWYgbm90IGFlcm9zcGlrZTpleGlzdHMocmVjKSB0aGVuCgkJcmV0dXJuICJub3JlYyIKCWVuZAoKCWluZm8ocmVjb3JkLnR0bChyZWMpKQoJaW5mbyhyZWNvcmQubGFzdF91cGRhdGVfdGltZShyZWMpKQoJcmV0dXJuIHJlY29yZC5sYXN0X3VwZGF0ZV90aW1lKHJlYykKZW5kCg==", "type": "LUA", "name": "lut.lua"}
```

Cross-checking : (Ignore the '' escape character added for the sake of echo command)

```
$ echo -n {\"content64\": \"ZnVuY3Rpb24gcHJpbnRfbWV0YShyZWMpCgoJaWYgbm90IGFlcm9zcGlrZTpleGlzdHMocmVjKSB0aGVuCgkJcmV0dXJuICJub3JlYyIKCWVuZAoKCWluZm8ocmVjb3JkLnR0bChyZWMpKQoJaW5mbyhyZWNvcmQubGFzdF91cGRhdGVfdGltZShyZWMpKQoJcmV0dXJuIHJlY29yZC5sYXN0X3VwZGF0ZV90aW1lKHJlYykKZW5kCg==\", \"type\": \"LUA\", \"name\": \"lut.lua\"} | sha1sum 
998354a59337b229e2dd777a3288e8e8f33568a5  -

$ asinfo -v "udf-list"
filename=lut.lua,hash=998354a59337b229e2dd777a3288e8e8f33568a5,type=LUA;
```

Comment: I tried sha1 on module source snd it doesn't match. Should I join filename and module content before calculating hash?

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer skipped many details. Please see the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @sunil answer

#### Python example

This routine calculates a hash for a LUA module with AeroSpike's UDF, written in **python 3**

```python
import base64
import hashlib

# You could pass one argument - full path, and then extract 
# name. But here we have only this naive implementation

def udf_module_get_hash(MODULE_PATH, MODULE_NAME_WITHOUT_DIR_WITH_EXT):
    with open(MODULE_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    b64 = base64.b64encode(content)

    meta = '{{"content64": "{0}", "type": "LUA", "name": "{1}"}}'.format(
        b64.decode('ascii'),
        MODULE_NAME_WITHOUT_DIR_WITH_EXT
    )
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha1.update(meta.encode())

    h = sha1.hexdigest()
    # h is something like '052ac7359e46d1c6c97a5bf1a9854739cd9e481a'
    return h
```